# Não consigo resolver um exercício de javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou fazendo um exercício e não consigo resolve-lo:

As instruções são:

Escreva a função eNumeroDaSorte que, recebendo um número, diz se é um número da sorte. Lembre-se de que o número deve obedecer às três condições mencionadas. Seu desafio adicional será: NÃO use o if.

Podemos dizer que é um número da sorte se o número:

é positivo

é um múltiplo de 2 ou 3

não é 15

A minha resposta foi:

```
function eNumeroDaSorte (numero) {

  return numero > 0 && 15%3==0 || 10%2==0 && numero != 15; 

}
```

Mas o site da errado com os seguintes problemas:

eNumeroDaSorte é falso e multiplo de 2 ou de 3

eNumeroDaSorte(7) é falso

eNumeroDaSorte(15) é falso

Agradeço por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Bom dia, embora você tenha dado informação suficiente pra darmos uma resposta, ao menos coloque um título na sua pergunta que se relacione ao seu problema. E sim, pensar em QUAL é o título da sua pergunta vai te tornar um melhor programador pois te levará ao processo de análise.

Comment: Ok, agradeço o comentário e vou tentar melhorar nas próximas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, alterei um pouco o código mas creio que `eNumeroDaSorte(15)` deve ser falso, de acordo com o que você descreveu, pois ele não é 15, mesmo sendo múltiplo de 3, e `eNumeroDaSorte(7)` também é falso pois não é múltiplo de 2 ou 3.

```js
function eNumeroDaSorte (numero) {
  return (numero >= 0) && ((numero % 3 === 0) || (numero % 2 === 0)) && (numero !== 15);
}

// é positivo
// é um múltiplo de 2 ou 3
// não é 15

console.log(eNumeroDaSorte(15))
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Oi, ajudou sim, muito obrigado. Acho que o prolema estava na parte da %, que eu tinha posto um 15%3 e 10%2. Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Minha resposta é:

```
function eNumeroDaSorte (numero) {
  return (numero > 0) && ((numero % 3 == 0) || (numero % 2 == 0)) && (numero !== 15);
}
```

numero não pode ser `>= 0` pois 0 não é múltiplo de 2 e 3
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

function eNumeroDaSorte (numero){
    return(numero > 0) && ((numero % 4 === 0) || (numero % 2 === 0))  &&  (numero  !== 15);
}
console.log(eNumeroDaSorte(15))

//Eu fiz assim e deu certo!espero ter ajudado!